# Arrays and listbox

Tags: c#, arrays, xaml, windows-phone-8, listbox

I am asking how to bind more than one array into listbox. This is example how a did with one array and one textblock in listbox

```
string[] Name={Terry, John, Edvard};

for(int i=0;i<Name.Lenght, i++)
ListBoxName.Items.Add(Name[i]);
```

XAML:

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxName">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Name=TextBlockName Text="{Binding}" />
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Ok. This is not a problem. Problems starts if a want to add other array to other textblock in same listbox:

```
string[] Name={Terry, John, Edvard};
string[] id= {122, 234, 665};

//??
```

XAML:

```
  <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxName">
                        <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                 <TextBlock Name="TextBlockName"/>
                                 <TextBlock Name="TextBlockid"/> 
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
    </ListBox>
```

I am working on WindowsPhone 8 application. This is just example.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting a compile error?

Comment: Why don't you join the lists and output a new object containing your properties you want in the listbox.

Comment: There is no compile problem i just want some example how to show or load two arrays in one listbox.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need a new class here with elements in all your arrays as properties, e.g.:

Code:

```
Class MyObject
{
    public string Name{get;set;}
    public string ID{get;set;}
}

MyObject[] MyObjectList = {new MyObject{Name="Terry",ID="122"}, new MyObject{Name="John",ID="234"},new MyObject{Name="Edvard",ID="665"}};

for(int i=0;i<MyObjectList.Lenght, i++)
ListBoxName.Items.Add(MyObjectList[i]);
```

XAML

```
<ListBox x:Name="ListBoxName">
                    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                        <DataTemplate>
                             <TextBlock Name="TextBlockName" Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                             <TextBlock Name="TextBlockid" Text="{Binding Path=ID}"/> 
                        </DataTemplate>
                    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

This will solve your problem, but do have a look of [`Data Binding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750612%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) as @Abbas also suggested.

Comment: This is exactly what I need. I apologize because the question is writed really weird. 
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

I would like to refer you to an answer of mine on a question here on SO: [**How can I data bind a list of strings to a ListBox in WPF/WP7?**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9391746/how-can-i-data-bind-a-list-of-strings-to-a-listbox-in-wpf-wp7).

Bottom line is,  I suggest you use `databinding` instead of iterating over an array and adding items. Using databinding, a class to hold properties and the MVVM pattern you can assign a viewmodel to the view. You bind this viewmodel to the view in which you extract the right information.

Short example (from my answer) a bit adapted to your situation:

XAML:

```
<ListBox Margin="20" ItemsSource="{Binding Items}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal">
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}" />
                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ID}" />
            </StackPanel>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Code:

```
public class NameIdClass
{
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string ID{ get; set; }
}

public class ViewModel
{
    public List<NameIdClass> Items
    {
        get
        {
            return new List<NameIdClass>
            {
                new NameIdClass { Name = "Terry", ID = 122 },
                new NameIdClass { Name = "John", ID = 234 }
            };
        }
    }
}

//This can be done in the Loaded event of the page:
DataContext = new MyViewModel();
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is similar to this question
   [Load a listbox with two textblock from a database with LINQ windows phone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21582770/load-a-listbox-with-two-textblock-from-a-database-with-linq-windows-phone)

If your issue is merging the two arrays (c# 3.0) then its as simple as

```
int[] first = { 1,2,3,4 }; // use  var instead array for illustration
int[] second = { 5,6,7,8 };
int[] combined = first.Concat(second).ToArray();
```

If this doesn't resolve your issue then please provide more information on what is the exact error.